# How to create download API to download files using python flask

Tags: python, api, flask, download

I have a python code which gives a download url of an image file from azure blob storage. If we copy paste this url in browser, it simply downloads the file. I have to create a download api which when called will simply download the file. Below is the code I have as of now:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import uuid
from flask_cors import CORS
from datetime import datetime
from azure.storage.blob import generate_blob_sas, AccountSasPermissions
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

uid_secret_key = str(uuid.uuid4())

app.secret_key = uid_secret_key

# Make the WSGI interface available at the top level so wfastcgi can get it.
wsgi_app = app.wsgi_app


@app.route('/download')
def download():
    account_name = "deeusblobstorage"
    container_name = "rperodct"
    blob_name = "face_1_7285.jpg"
    account_key = "hMlIRXCjAomfDRfied8Y5FPwTVnWEkEDuVsw//CQtkiOdcFD/y5wUcxH9Ou7Ni+DtDQFwe23YbZ3Qia9gw=="
    url = f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{container_name}/{blob_name}"
    sas_token = generate_blob_sas(
        account_name=account_name,
        account_key=account_key,
        container_name=container_name,
        blob_name=blob_name,
        permission=AccountSasPermissions(read=True),
        expiry=datetime.datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)
    )

    url_with_sas = f"{url}?{sas_token}"
    print(url_with_sas)
    urlopen(url_with_sas)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return jsonify({'Status': 'ok', 'date': '05.25.21'}), 200


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os

    HOST = os.environ.get('SERVER_HOST', 'localhost')
    try:
        PORT = int(os.environ.get('SERVER_PORT', '5555'))
    except ValueError:
        PORT = 5555
    app.run(HOST, PORT)
```

`/download` api contains the code which gets the download url of a blob from azure container in variable name `url_with_sas`. Now I want to make this API in such a way that if we hit this, it should automatically download the file from the url. So for this I thought of adding `urlopen(url_with_sas)` which will open the url. But seems like its not working. Can anyone give some suggestions for this. Thanks

Comment: are you trying to download it so the client is downloading the file or should it be saved on the server? Have you tried using `requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)`, i've never used urlopen for this case tbh

Comment: @shiny  Yes I am trying to download. This API will be integrated with a button, so user will click the button and the file will be downloaded on his browser. Let me try your suggestion

Comment: @shiny It didn't worked

Comment: ok, let me set up your code and try something

Comment: ok, i've tried to make simple `return redirect(url_with_sas)` so the user is getting redirected directly to the right location, but i'm not able to reach the site. Can you confirm, that you are able to download anything with the gerneated link in `url_with_sas`?

Comment: @shiny Thanks it worked fine with redirect. In my question I modified the account name and key thats why it didnt worked. If you can answer, I will accept. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comment mentioned the solution is via a `return redirect(url_with_sas)`
so the whole function looks like this:

```
@app.route('/download')
def download():
    account_name = "deeusblobstorage"
    container_name = "rperodct"
    blob_name = "face_1_7285.jpg"
    account_key = "hMlIRXCjAomfDRfied8Y5FPwTVnWEkEDuVsw//CQtkiOdcFD/y5wUcxH9Ou7Ni+DtDQFwe23YbZ3Qia9gw=="
    url = f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{container_name}/{blob_name}"
    sas_token = generate_blob_sas(
        account_name=account_name,
        account_key=account_key,
        container_name=container_name,
        blob_name=blob_name,
        permission=AccountSasPermissions(read=True),
        expiry=datetime.datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)
    )

    url_with_sas = f"{url}?{sas_token}"
    return redirect(url_with_sas)
```